# Offset brush when using graphics2d

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, graphics2d

Is it possible to offset the brush by a given amount when drawing in the paintComponent? The end result would be everything drawn offset by an X and Y value.

Comment: Not directly.  You'd have to offset the shapes you're outlining or drawing to offset the brush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to translate all the graphics then you can do:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics g2 = g.create();
    g2.translate(xValue, yValue);

    // do custom painting

   g2.dispose();
}
```